# Why does this Python code with threading have race conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gil

This code creates a race condition:

```
import threading

ITERS = 100000
x = [0]

def worker():
    for _ in range(ITERS):
        x[0] += 1  # this line creates a race condition
        # because it takes a value, increments and then writes
        # some inrcements can be done together, and lost

def main():
    x[0] = 0  # you may use `global x` instead of this list trick too
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

for i in range(5):
    main()
    print(f'iteration {i}. expected x = {ITERS*2}, got {x[0]}')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py
iteration 0. expected x = 200000, got 200000
iteration 1. expected x = 200000, got 148115
iteration 2. expected x = 200000, got 155071
iteration 3. expected x = 200000, got 200000
iteration 4. expected x = 200000, got 200000
```

Python3 version:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
```

I thought GIL would prevent it and not allow two threads run together until they do something io-related or call a C library. At least this is what you may conclude from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

Turns out I was wrong. Then, what does GIL actually do, and when do threads run in parallel?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717393/is-the-operator-thread-safe-in-python and especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266186/is-extending-a-python-list-e-g-l-1-guaranteed-to-be-thread-safe

Comment: This shouldn't be the job for a lock? I mean why don't you use a lock when adding the number of the list? Operation on list do not guarantee atomicity.  Have u tried with a lock and the same occur? Also I think using a  deque should ensure more atomicity than a simple list. There was an stackoverflow answer where Alex martelli points out that you should you a combination of deque and queue when using threading

Comment: aaaaand https://web.archive.org/web/20201108091210/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

Comment: @FedericoBaù it should, of course, when you know this is going to happen. When I learned Python and tried multithreading a decade ago, it seemed that it should be like Javascript, that executes an entire function until it ends and lets the event loop go on.

Comment: @culebrón found the alex martelli opinion regarding threading https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846697/13903942

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, that's where the example code came originally.

Comment: @culebrón ahh yes but is quite different than javascript for sure. I understand the javascript background now because you use race considin and used off course for async work.normally when talking about python threading I normally read block non blocking ;)

Comment: Try it with Python 3.10, I think there was a recent interesting Q&A that pointed out that this doesn't happen anymore (though it's not safe to assume it doesn't).

Comment: i implement this code (`python 3.10`, `windows10`), and do not get the issue. all my "got values" were as expected...  so a version / platform issue.

Comment: @D.L I tested in on my new Ubuntu with Python 3.10, and it also stopped having race condition. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) better, I think there's the answer:

> The mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that **only one thread executes Python bytecode at a time**. This simplifies the CPython implementation by making the object model (including critical built-in types such as dict) implicitly safe against concurrent access. Locking the entire interpreter makes it easier for the interpreter to be multi-threaded, at the expense of much of the parallelism afforded by multi-processor machines.

> However, some extension modules, either standard or third-party, are designed so as to release the GIL when doing computationally-intensive tasks such as compression or hashing. Also, the GIL is always released when doing I/O.

I guess this means that each line of source code consists of multiple blocks of bytecode. Bytecode lines/blocks are atomic, i.e. they get executed alone, but the source lines aren't.

Here's the byte code that `+=1` exapands to (run `dis.dis('x[0] += 1')` to see):

```
          0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
          2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          4 DUP_TOP_TWO
          6 BINARY_SUBSCR
          8 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         10 INPLACE_ADD
         12 ROT_THREE
         14 STORE_SUBSCR
         16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
         18 RETURN_VALUE
```

When these lines are executed in concurrent way, race condition occurs.

So, GIL does not save you from it. It only prevents race conditions that could damage complex structures like `list` or `dict`.

Comment: use `dis.dis("x[0] += 1")`

Answer (score 1):

As per our final comments, it appears as though this has been fixed (ubuntu, windows) with `python version 3.10` and above. This issue is no longer experienced.

However, there other scenarios where race conditions can be obsevered. For example this:

```py
import threading
import time
 
x = 10
 
def increment(by):
    global x
 
    local_counter = x
    local_counter += by
 
    time.sleep(1)
 
    x = local_counter
    print(f'{threading.current_thread().name} inc x {by}, x: {x}')
 
def main():
    # creating threads
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=(5,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=increment, args=(10,))
   
    # starting the threads
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
   
    # waiting for the threads to complete
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
   
    print(f'The final value of x is {x}')
 
for i in range(10):
    main()
```

which produces this:

```
Thread-56 (increment) inc x 10, x: 20Thread-55 (increment) inc x 5, x: 15
 
The final value of x is 15
Thread-57 (increment) inc x 5, x: 20Thread-58 (increment) inc x 10, x: 25
 
The final value of x is 25
Thread-60 (increment) inc x 10, x: 35Thread-59 (increment) inc x 5, x: 30
 
The final value of x is 30
Thread-61 (increment) inc x 5, x: 35
Thread-62 (increment) inc x 10, x: 40
The final value of x is 40
Thread-64 (increment) inc x 10, x: 50Thread-63 (increment) inc x 5, x: 45
 
The final value of x is 45
```

but the fix here is to use the `asyncio` module to control the flow of the code.